# Reading Elements within a Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://www.someurl.com/somefile.xslt"?>
<AutoInsuranceClaim xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/schemas/AutoInsuranceClaim">
    <Identification>
        <BaseOwner>3</BaseOwner>
        <BaseType>ABC123</BaseType>
        <BaseTypeRef>471038341757</BaseTypeRef>
    </Identification>
</AutoInsuranceClaim>
```

and I'm trying to read the Identification node.  Here's my code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"..\..\Data.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.someurl.com/schemas/AutoInsuranceClaim");

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"/ns:AutoInsuranceClaim/Identification", nsmgr);

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} nodes...", nodeList.Count);
```

I know I should get a least 1 value.  My understanding of .NET XML parsing is that if you have a default namespace with no prefix, you have to create your own namespace.  But this should have returned 1.

If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you try `@"/ns:AutoInsuranceClaim/ns:Identification"`?

Comment: Have you tried `xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("AutoInsuranceClaim", "http://www.someurl.com/schemas/AutoInsuranceClaim")` ?

Comment: @Oded,  Looks like I've got more reading to do.  I didn't realize I needed to prefix every node with the namespace.  Cheers

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-namespaces/info, and [tag:xml-namespaces] in general.

Answer (score 2):

I might be grasping at straws here, but shouldn't you be namespacing both entities in your xpath expression?

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"/ns:AutoInsuranceClaim/ns:Identification", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load("Data.xml");
        var identifications = root.Descendants()
           .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Identification")
           .ToList()
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't this load the *entire* document in memory?

Comment: you do the same but with less convenient manner XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"..\..\Data.xml");

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to find an `Identification` node *without* a namespace, but it will have defaulted to the same namespace as the parent due to the `xmlns=...` part. Try this:

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ns:AutoInsuranceClaim/ns:Identification", 
                                  nsmgr);
```

Having tried it myself, it printed a count of 1.

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML instead though, which makes namespace easier handling:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Data.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.someurl.com/schemas/AutoInsuranceClaim";
var nodes = doc.Root.Elements(ns + "Identification");
```

Comment: Why not thru xelement? it's more simpler and nicer :)

Comment: @GSerjo: Given that the OP really *has* a document (with a document declaration etc) I feel that XDocument is more suitable. It's really not that much simpler - and using `XNamespace` is much cleaner than comparing the LocalName IMO.

Comment: XElement version is more maintainable and doesn't require hard code namespace IMO

Comment: @GSerjo: In what way is it more maintainable? What's so much better about XElement than XDocument in your opinion? Note that although it doesn't require hard-coding the namespace, it could give false positives if the document has the *wrong* namespace. You could always fetch the namespace of the root element if you want to always use that.

Comment: It's really strange get namespace from root and use this one for search

Comment: @GSerjo: Why do you think that's "strange" but "ignore the namespace completely and hope it's right" is good?

Comment: If namespace is used always it's strange, if namespace is in the way then help it's strange. Where you can get the namespace: 1) Hard-coding, 2) From root 3) From outside (as  a parameter for example). *1* it's smell code, but anything can happen. *2* get the namespace from root use this and use this one for search strange because almost always you can do it without the namespace. Yes, sometime namespase is ver useful for example version support, but it's very small part of use IMO.

Comment: @GSerjo: My point is that if you ignore the namespace, it makes it more fragile. You're hard-coding the element name already... why is hard-coding the namespace any different?

Comment: @GSerjo: Oh, and you still haven't explained why you think it's better to load a file which is a *document* into an XElement instead of an XDocument...

Comment: I see your point, but more often you can do the same without the namespace. Yes, element name has been had-coded, but only element name, one is less than two (element+namespace). Another point namespace can be replaced by context, for example method call. i.e. method know what type of data is supported and you can try create concrete class, so namespace has been replaced. About XElement vs XDocument, my fault, it was slightly incorrect question

Comment: @GSerjo: You could easily argue that actually you're currently hardcoding *half* a name, whereas I'm hardcoding a whole name - the full name of the element really includes its namespace, therefore I'm being more consistent. I suspect we'll have to agree to disagree though.